# I have a issue in array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

**why It is print/console false...????**

```
function isWin(arr){
    const conditions=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9],[1,5,9],[3,5,7]]; //wining constions
    arr=arr.sort();
    let result=conditions.forEach((eachCondtions)=>{
    console.log(eachCondtions===arr)        //false
    })


isWin([4,5,6]);
```

Comment: Also, `forEach` doesn't return anything meaningful (only `undefined`).

Comment: i think it is a bug in javascript if i you want to compare two arrays you have to use `JSON.stringify(array)` @Teemu

Comment: It's not a bug, it's by design.